# How to generate random variables from a probability density function/ probability mass function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-science, probability-density

I am trying simulate random arrival times for cars that will park in a small parking lot. I want to use a random generator to create random parking events. I am not sure if numpy is the correct library for this job.

Example:
I use randint to generate the number of cars that will park on that day randint(3, high = 20), then I use the Poisson random variable generator to output the charging times in seconds in a day (k-index) [0 – 86,399] with a mean of 35,999 (10:00)

I tried using `np.random.poisson(lam=(35999.), size=(np.random.randint(3, high = 20), 1))`, but the random variables seem to be too centered around 35,999

```
array([[35843],
       [35923],
       [35872],
       [36118],
       [36426],
       [35998]])
array([[36163],
       [35895],
       [35756],
       [35799],
       [36240],
       [36397]])
array([[36001],
       [36256],
       [36084],
       [36201]])
array([[36002],
       [35888],
       [36200],
       [36035],
       [35931],
       [35688],
       [36054],
       [36251],
       [35968],
       [35888],
       [35732],
       [35503],
       [36076],
       [36131],
       [35994],
       [36075]])
```

I am looking for values with a higher variance like:

```
get_poisson_rv(lam = 35999, size = randint(3,high = 20))

array([[16547],
       [35923],
       [29300],
       [43456],
       [51234],
       [70754]])
array([[12473],
       [28792],
       [33543],
       [38967],
       [44563],
       [56373]])
array([[6598],
       [27650],
       [38982],
       [45632]])
array([[2564],
       [8734],
       [15267],
       [22543],
       [28965],
       [32054],
       [36658],
       [38251],
       [43968],
       [44888],
       [49732],
       [53503],
       [58076],
       [68131],
       [74994],
       [82350]])
```

I am not sure if a Poisson function is the best method for this, and how I could increase the variance. Also, is there a way for python to generate a mixed or compound Poisson function. Apologies for any naive question, I am new to use random generators for multiple peak times. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

To understand what's going on with your distribution and the numbers we get, we need to look at the formula of the standard deviation of the `Poisson` distribution, which is the square root of `lambda` ([source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/poisson-distribution)), called `lam` in `numpy`.

The square root of your lambda (`35999`) is ~`190`. This is why you get so little variation - you basically specified a random distribution with the mean of `35999` and a standard deviation of `190`, that is to say your results won't fluctuate much by design.

Moreover, please bear in mind that the `Poisson` distribution is approximately a `normal` distribution for large `lambda`, where `large` is already considered `lam=20` in the world of statistics ([source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/poisson-distribution)), so you could also use a `normal` distribution with your custom `standard deviation` to achieve your desired outcome.

I personally would suggest you to first think about what kind of pattern you would like to model and then see what makes sense from an implementation perspective. What I can see from your description is that you plan to model charging times of electronic vehicles. There are scientific papers out there on that topic, and surely some of them mention what kind of distribution they use to model charging times - once you know the conventional distribution which is used in that community it should be fairly easy to find its implementation in python.